# JQUERY Fade slideshow without white in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fade

I have a slideshow on this Wordpress website [www.2eenheid.de](http://www.2eenheid.de). I am trying to figure out how to make the images fade so it **fades** between the images instead of fading into a white bg color first and then into an image. Any clue how to do this in my situation, see below?

**The javascript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var imgsrc = '';
            imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');

            $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
                var newImg = $(this).attr('src');
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
                    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                });

            }, function () {
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': imgsrc
                    }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="slideshow-main">
  <ul class="slideshow-menu">
   <li class=""><a title="Support / Beheer" href="/supportenbeheer" src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg"><img src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Support / Beheer</span></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="/implementatie" src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg"><img src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Implementatie</span></a></li>
   <li class="current_page_item"><a href="/cloud" src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg"><img src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Cloud</span></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="/webhosting-en-hosting" src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg"><img src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Webhosting / Hosting</span></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="/unit4-multivers" src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg"><img src="http://www.2eenheid.de/wp-content/themes/2eenheid/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Unit4 Multivers</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the opacity for the class `pikachoose` to 1

```
.pikachoose 
{
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did, but now it doesn't fade at all anymore. (See site for effect)

Comment: fading means opacity being reduced from 1 to 0 of an image and the next images opacity being increased from 0 to 1....in the questuion yiu have mentioned u dont need fading...so i gave this solution...i dont knw with fading what yoou are expecting?

Comment: Oh i do want to keep the fading, but without the white bg in between. I typed it wrong with Toggle. Editing it..

Comment: fading beaviour is such..u might be wanting some other animation..not fading

Answer (score 0):

do this with z-index.

CSS

```
#slideshow-main { position: relative }   

.slideshow-main img {z-index: 1; position: absolute; }

.slideshow-main img.active {z-index: 3; }
```

JQUERY

```
function cycleImages(){

      var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }
$(function(){
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 10000);
});
```